# How to store image in redux, image return an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to store image to redux store,
but it still give me empty object.

[image]

When I console.log the image, it has the following specification

[image]

here's my code

```
    onClickSave = () => {
        if (this.editor) {
            // If you want the image resized to the canvas size (also a HTMLCanvasElement)
            const canvas = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas();

            canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                const file = new File([blob], "my-file", {
                    type: "image/png",
                });

                console.log(file) // return the object in the picture above
                this.props.handlePicture(file); // trying store to redux, but failed 
            });
        }
    };
```

heres my action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handlePicture: file => {
            return dispatch({type: PRODUCT_ADD_PICTURE, payload: file })
        }
    }
}
```

My reducer

```
// import things 

const initialState = {
    name: "",
    description: "",
    picture: null,
    quantity: 0,
};
const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const payload = action.payload
    switch (action.type) {
        // other code
        case PRODUCT_ADD_PICTURE: {
            console.log('here paylaod', payload)
            return { ...state, picture: payload };
        }
       // other code
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Heres log result in the reducer.

[image]

Usually when I store it to redux it gives me some string, and ready to send it to the server.
Why it is return empty?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `handlePicture` do? Please include its implementation. If you are dispatching actions to store anything in your store then please also include the relevant action and reducer functions. Please clarify what is failing, or rather, what the failure is. Are there any errors? What debugging steps have you undertaken so far?

Comment: If you drop another console.log in the `case PRODUCT_ADD_PICTURE` to log the action payload do you see the correct value there in the reducer? Can you track the action via the redux-dev-tools in the browser?

Comment: @DrewReese yes I already update the question

Comment: Where are you calling to get the image?

Comment: Ok, so it seems you are able to update your state. Where are you then trying to select this `picture` state? Where it's undefined?